# Can I create a table with columns named similar to field value of another table, return by SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[Question Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pt0VJ.png)

When I execute this script, there is a syntax error. What is wrong with this?

```
use TEST
go

CREATE TABLE newTagsTable 
( 
     (SELECT TEST.dbo.dynamicTags.Alais 
      FROM TEST.dbo.dynamicTags 
      WHERE ID = 2) varchar(200)
);
```

Comment: Database that you use ?

Comment: SQl Server 2008 R2

Comment: FYI, SQL Server 2008R2 has been unsupported for over a year now, @SamraatRajput , you should really be looking at upgrade paths.

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to achieve here with the above. VBoka might be right with an `INTO` here, but the logic you have doesn't quite seem right for an `INTO` as you still define the data type.

Comment: @SamraatRajput your feedback would be nice. To this comment from Larnu or to my answer ...

Comment: @Larnu here is what i exactly want to do ..... ..
I have table with Column, in Which there are 10 field values 

B20_FIT001,
B20_FIT002,
B20_FIT003,
B20_FIT004,
B20_FIT005,
B20_FIT006,
B20_FIT007,
B20_FIT008,
B20_FIT009,
B20_FIT101,

Now i want create a new Table with Column name as 'B20_FIT001','B20_FIT002','B20_FIT003'......

i could do it manually ,but if there are 100 entry in previous column ?

Comment: [Edit] Your question, that comment makes no sense, @SamraatRajput

Comment: @Larnu i have attached a question image ,that is what i want to do

Comment: Don't post images of code and data, @SamraatRajput . Put code and data as `text`; that is what it is after all.

Comment: Side, note, that is a *really* old version of SSMS; I suggest updating to the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need ?

```
SELECT Alais 
into newTagsTable 
FROM dynamicTags 
WHERE ID = 2;
```

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=caee2c0d48ecdb4615aea6b376309f99)

Ok, so something like this then:

```
create procedure test_proc
as
declare @p_sql varchar(2000);
declare @p_sql_2 varchar(2000);
declare @getid CURSOR;

SET @getid = CURSOR FOR
SELECT Alais
FROM   dynamicTags;

begin
    set @p_sql = 'create table newTagsTable (';
    
    OPEN @getid
    FETCH NEXT
    FROM @getid INTO @p_sql_2
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin
        set @p_sql = @p_sql + @p_sql_2 + ' varchar(20),'
        FETCH NEXT FROM @getid INTO @p_sql_2
    end;
    
    set @p_sql = left(@p_sql, len(@p_sql)-1) + ')';
    
    EXEC (@p_sql);
    
end;
```

And then just execute the procedure:

```
exec test_proc
```

You can add parameters to this to make it more usable for orher situations...
Here is the demo for this second option:

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bbf908f32c804b9fa33c6a6e6fbea378)

Comment: Hi @SamraatRajput, you have asked for help here and help was provided. The minimum you can do is to thank and comment on the answers provided ?